# Generate random numbers from empirical cumulative distribution function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I generated an empirical cumulative distribution function in MATLAB via

```
x = [1, 1.2, ..., 1]
[myECDF, xi] = ecdf(x);
```

Now I would like to use this ECDF as a basis to draw a set of random numbers from. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
y = random(myECDF, 10);  // drawing 10 random numbers from ECDF
```

Is this possible in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the inverse CDF method.  Generate uniformly distributed random variables between 0 and 1 and treat them as CDF outputs.  Then use your empirical distribution to find the corresponding values.

```
function my_x = my_random(myECDF, xi, N)
    % Generate N uniformly distributed samples between 0 and 1.
    u = rand(N,1);
    % Map these to the points on the empirical CDF.
    my_x = interp1(myECDF, xi, u, 'linear');
end
```